# Navbar toggle button isn't working in react Using Bootstrap 4.5.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

Why my toggle button is not working. I'm creating a **react app**! Please help
Should I try with ul li tags or is there any library that makes responsive navbar for react?

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
        MoviesLix
      </Link>
      <button
        className="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div className="navbar-nav">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/movies">
            Movies<span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/customers">
            Customers
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/rentals">
            Rentals
          </NavLink>
          {!user && (
            <React.Fragment>
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/login">
                Login
              </NavLink>
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/register">
                Register
              </NavLink>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          {user && (
            <React.Fragment>
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/profile">
                {user.name}
              </NavLink>
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/logout">
                Logout
              </NavLink>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

When clicking button navbar isn't opening in mobile rest everything working good i dont know why this happening

Comment: There is no `onClick` event attached to the button. How do you use Bootstrap in your project? Please, don't tell me you're using jQuery with React.

Comment: No, I'm not using jquery. Thank you for your answer I revised the latest version of react from youtube it solved my problem as I'm using class based structure which is older.

Answer (score 0):

React basically works with components and it's lifecycles. To use Bootstrap with it you should install Bootstrap and React Bootstrap modules using npm or yarn like so:

**Using Yarn:**
`yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap`

**Using NPM:**
`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

After that you can access the React Bootstrap documentations to learn how to use it's components. You can access it [clicking here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/).

The main problem with your code is that you are trying to use toggle through bootstrap's vanilla methods. It was made to work with vanilla JavaScript and React will not understand it as JQuery would.

You'll have to create a React component's state and a controller function, then validate the state to render the you nav or hide it. You can check out this example that I wrote to you:

```
  const [toggle, setIsToggled] = useState(() => false); // this is a react hook to handle component states
  
  function handleToggleNavbar() { // this function is the controller of your toggle button
    setIsToggled(currentStateValue => { // useState returns a callback with the current state value
      return !currentStateValue; //inverting the toggle state value
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ok i'll try this and reply asap. thank you for the ans.